# UICollectionView with spacing between cells has scrolling issues

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

i have a collection view, with cells in a size of the all screen.
i'm trying to add spacing between the cells, so when ever i scroll between the cells there will be some space between - as in the iOS photo gallery, when you scroll between full screen images.

obviously i have paging enabled.
but for some reason when i scroll between the cells, the spacing is staying on the screen.
i.e. if the cell width is 320, and the space between the next cell is 20px, so when i scroll to the next cell, the space is reaching to x=0, and the new cell starts at x=20.

why is that?
how do i get the exact iOS photo gallery scrolling full screen images effect?

Comment: Please post relevant code (or maybe screenshots from a storyboard / XIB if you use one).

Answer (score 0):

increase the width of the collection to the space value and shift collection left to the half space value. then change right and left section insets to the half space value

[image]

or you can make your own paging that will works even if cell size are less then collection view:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGPoint contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    CGSize size = scrollView.frame.size;
    CGPoint locationInView = CGPointMake(contentOffset.x + size.width/2, contentOffset.y + size.height/2);
    if (scrollView == _collectionView) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:locationInView];
        [_collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally];
        [self collectionView:_collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
    if (!decelerate) {
        [self scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:scrollView];
    }
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:YES];
}
```